# How to programatically tell when FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT has expired in the Android FIngerprintManager?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-fingerprint-api

When my app hits the "Too Many Attempts...", authentication error 0x7, FINGERPRINT_ERROR_LOCKOUT, how can I tell without calling FingerprintManager.authenticate() in a loop and getting the error that the lockout condition is cleared?

Comment: Among the many things I tried was calling `hasEnrolledFingerprints()` and
`isHardwareDetected()` during the lockout period in order to see if it would return or throw some sort of exception. No luck there, those calls work as expected.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I would also like to know the lockout time remaining and if the device is locked before calling authenticate().

Comment: @Niels I have not pursued this anymore but a quick look through the latest version of the FingerprintManager.java source code shows me something like this:    `public static abstract class LockoutResetCallback {

        //Called when lockout period expired and clients are allowed to listen for fingerprint again.
        public void onLockoutReset() { }
    }`

Comment: I bet the onLockoutReset() tells you asynchronously when the lockout period ended...  However, I have not tested this.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the AOSP implementation of the system FingerprintService, there is actually a broadcast intent that gets sent out after the lockout period has expired.  The intent action to look for is `com.android.server.fingerprint.ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET`.

In your Activity, you can register a broadcast receiver and wait for this intent, like so:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private static final String ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET =
        "com.android.server.fingerprint.ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET";

    private final BroadcastReceiver mLockoutReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                doWhateverYouNeedToDoAfterLockoutHasBeenReset();
            }
        }
    };

    private void registerLockoutResetReceiver() {
        Intent ret = getContext().registerReceiver(mLockoutReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET),
                null, null);
    }


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        registerLockoutResetReceiver();
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

**WARNING:** this is not part of the public API and so, this behavior may change with any later OS update.  But I did try it on Nougat and it works quite well for me.

Reference:

The relevant AOSP code is [./frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/fingerprint/FingerprintService.java](http://androidxref.com/7.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/fingerprint/FingerprintService.java).  In this file, we can find a `PendingIntent` with an `ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET` intent being created:

```
private PendingIntent getLockoutResetIntent() {
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,
            new Intent(ACTION_LOCKOUT_RESET), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}
```

This PendingIntent is registered to be set off after some elapsed time by the AlarmManager:

```
private void scheduleLockoutReset() {
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + FAIL_LOCKOUT_TIMEOUT_MS, getLockoutResetIntent());
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but after I receive the broadcast, the fingerprint device would not react to any fingerprint scanning. I had to restart activity to rescan. Anyone seeing similar issue?

Comment: @JeffreyLiu After the lockout, you have to restart your Fingerprint Device manager.

Comment: How do you restart?@hopia

Comment: You call cancel() on the CancellationSignal object you registered when you started the fingerprint manager:  mCancellationSignal.cancel();   And then you call mFingerPrintManager.authenticate() again.